# Predictive writing just suggests me my friend's names!

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-gio, text-prediction

I've just installed ICS on my Samsung GT-s5660. The Italian dictionary is installed, but still I can't get suggestions when I'm writing. It just suggests me names from my address book and punctuation marks. I could use another keyboard instead of the native one, but I don't like them.

Could it be because of that "Japanese IME" installed by default? I can't de-select it!

Thank you in advance! :)